# How do I customize Haddock document generation, for all packages?

Tags: haskell, config, haddock

It's not clear to me how to customize the documents that

```
cabal haddock
```

generates. For example how do I include source links, or use a custom CSS file so that they apply in all cases?

In my `~/.cabal/config` I've tried

```
haddock
  -- keep-temp-files: False
  -- hoogle: False
  -- html: False
  -- html-location:
  -- executables: False
  -- tests: False
  -- benchmarks: False
  -- all:
  -- internal: False
  css: /Users/Rax/Projects/Haskell/Package/mystuff.css
  hyperlink-source: True
  -- hscolour-css:
  -- contents-location:
```

but it's unclear to me what the scope if these settings is.

How do I customize the default document generation for all documents generated by Haddock: packages I build with `cabal haddock`, for packages I install from Hackage with `cabal install`, and even to packages I upload to Hackage with `cabal sdist`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the settings in `~/.cabal/config` are your per-user default settings. Your alterations would come into effect, whenever you call `cabal haddock`.

Since the haddock documentation is built statically for each package, you would need to rerun the `cabal haddock` command for every package you install to change the appearance of its docs.

Also you seem to have mixed up something a little: `cabal sdist` does not upload anything to Hackage. That's what `cabal upload` is for.

Usually you just upload the bare package to Hackage and the server builds the documentation himself, but there is a way to upload the documentation you built yourself, in case the server fails to build it or for other reasons. I use the following script I found at http://hackage.haskell.org/upload with some alterations:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

dir=$(mktemp -d dist-docs.XXXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf "$dir"' EXIT

cabal haddock --builddir="$dir" --for-hackage --haddock-option=--hyperlinked-source
# Starting with cabal 2.0, `--publish` is needed for uploading to non-candidate releases
cabal upload -d $dir/*-docs.tar.gz --publish
```